# Laravel workbench unit test

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, workbench

What is the way to test my packages in workbench. If I write a unit test then no classes are autoloaded. So this means that:

```
<?php

use \Mockery as m;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

public function tearDown()
{
    m::close();
}

/**
 * A basic functional test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testShouldReturnValidServer()
{

    $mock = m::mock('MailChimp[sendCurl]');

    MailChimp::listSubscribe( array( 'id' => 'c79a023ff2', 'email_address' => 'dennieriechelman@gmail.com'));

   }
}
```

results in a error saying that class TestCase is not found. When I add class TestCase to the autoload in my composer.json (the one in my package folder) the class is available. However then I get the next error that "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase" is not available etc. etc. 
So my question is what should I autoload in my composer.json in my package folder? Everything just like in my main composer.json or is there some other way that I am missing.

I know that in the manuel it says"

> You may git init from the workbench/[vendor]/[package] directory and git push your package straight from the workbench! This will allow you to conveniently develop the package in an application context without being bogged down by constant composer update commands.

However I do not understand this. Can someone explain what is meant with this? By the way I am familiar with git. I just do not get the context.

EDIT1
As far I understand now is that you push your package to your repository and then include it in your main composer.json as package. I just do not see how this is helpful when developing. Hopefully I understand this wrong.. :)

EDIT2
I was wrong. You keep your package in workbench until it stable. Just like Nils pointed out below.The question still remains though. How do I create an environment in which I can unit test with the app started. I mean like testing a model where I can mock the facades etc. Or is doing this in the workbench bad practice?

Comment: The manual says exactly the opposite: If you keep your package in workbench during the development you do not have to use composer. Once it is stable and you want to use it elsewhere you would add it to composer.json.

Comment: Thanks. That is true. Then where is the git push sentence about?

Comment: Well you want to have your bundle (the one that is currently in `workbench`) to be under version control but decoupled from `composer`. So if you're using git, you can do `git push` in your `workspace`. Your bundle will not show up in `composer.json` but be installable in your system.

Comment: Yes Okay. That makes sense. That is how I thought that it was meant but I was confused. So this means that I have manually add the dependencies in the composer.json of the package. Thanks

Comment: I have answered at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391078/747802 what worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I created a package for this purpose at https://github.com/orchestral/testbench

Comment: How would you run your workbench tests? `phpunit` from `workbench/vendor/package` or from the laravel root?

Do you have to update the laravel `phpunit.xml` file or add one to your workbench package?

Comment: I would like some clarification as well

Comment: This package has just become my new favorite.

Comment: Thank you, this was an absolute life saver. For those that are struggling with this, carefully read through [the git example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/orchestral/testbench/master/tests/DatabaseFixtureTest.php) and step your way through the process.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind merging the results of your workbench testing with the results of your main application, you can simply add extra directories to your main phpunit.xml in your laravel root like this:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./app/tests/phpunit/</directory>
        <directory>./workbench/vendor/packageOne/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./workbench/vendor/packageTwo/tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Then in the tests folder of your package, place your phpunit tests as normal, along with the TestCase.php file, adjusting the createApplication() function to be:

```
<?php

class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

public function createApplication()
{
    $unitTesting = true;
    $testEnvironment = 'testing';
    return require './bootstrap/start.php';
}
```

Make sure your package composer.json auto-loads that TestCase.php file like so:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/phpunit/TestCase.php"           
    ]
}
```

Run composer dump-autoload -o to get everything aligned and then you should be able to run phpunit from your laravel root and it will test both your application and your packages.

Answer (score 0):

Extend from the proper namespace and you should be able to run tests from package dir.

```
class ExampleTest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {
    ..
}
```

See also [Laravels neat testing helpers in workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635117/1165509)