# Laravels neat testing helpers in workbench?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, workbench

Looking at the [laravel testing documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/testing), you get an idea of all the cool helpers I'd love to use in workbench.

Sadly I'm unable to do so.

`Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` seems to be unavailable when running my tests from the package directory and therefore i can't extend it.

```
<?php namespace Acme\Foo;

    class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;

        $testEnvironment = 'testing';

        return require __DIR__.'/../../../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }

}

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Webseiten/acme/workbench/acme/foo/tests/TestCase.php on line 3
```

I think thats not the correct way, this should be done anyways...

I have already found [orchestral/testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) but I'm not really sure if it is a good idea to use it. It seems to require the whole laravel framework, which doesn't make sense to me? ( A package should extend a laravel install and not add the framework a second time!? )

Comment: It add the whole framework because that would be missing if you for example push the package to github and run it on travis-ci.

Comment: so add `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"` to the packages composer.json `"require-dev"` would be a good practice?

Comment: It was added to ensure that when you require 2.0, it load laravel 4.0, and when you're loading 2.1, it load laravel 4.1 and so on in the future.

Does it make any different? probably only for those that use it only on workbench but then again loading two composer vendor in one app is still a bad idea.

At this stage I'm not really focusing to support workbench which cause issues such as https://github.com/orchestral/testbench#working-with-workbench and https://github.com/orchestral/testbench/issues/29

Comment: Okay, i see. So if i just `"require-dev"` `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"` it probably won't work. `testbench`is there to fix these problems but currently behaves buggy on 4.1... Is there any good alternative? What is the best way to develop laravel packages with travis-ci testing – Leave workbench alone and do it completely different?

Comment: My advice would be use workbench just an early stage of understanding package development. Once you're familiar with it move it out and continue working on it as an independent package, for so many reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, because of the way workbench is setup, the test cases can only extend from PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. So I run the test cases from the app folder instead of the package folder.

I choose the second option as testbench heavily depends on the particular Laravel version and seems a bit heavy to set up. What I did is configure the phpunit.xml under the main app to include the package tests folder as a test suite:

```
<testsuite name="MyPack">
    <directory>./workbench/winponta/mypack/tests/</directory>
</testsuite>
```

And then run:

```
$ phpunit --testsuite=MyPack
```

Using this method, we can still extends from \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.

I found this solution at http://ngo-hung.com/blog/2014/04/16/laravel-unit-testing-in-workbench-note

Comment: Yeah, that's a good solution. Only problem arises once you want to have some sort of CI going. (e.g. Travis, which is the case for me) Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: Well, I still not using CI inthis Laravel project, so didn't have to think about it. Your welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I just did like this,

First of all, change your `phpunit.xml` content on your workbench directory. You will "bootstrap" attribute section, change it from `vendor/autoload.php` to `../../../bootstrap/autoload.php`

Then try running `phpunit` on your workbench directory.

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the bootstrap option on the command line (if you don't want to alter the config file): `phpunit --bootstrap=../../../bootstrap/autoload.php`

Comment: This is great, both answers helped me out greatly, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Removing

> namespace Acme\Foo;

should fix it. Then you can run tests from the package dir. Also be sure to run *composer dump-autoload* in the package dir or *php artisan dump-autoload* from main app dir.

**UPDATE** I was able to replicate the error in a clean Laravel 4.1 installation and fixed it following this steps without installing extra packages:

**1** - Install PHPUnit in the main laravel root *composer.json* (not the workbench package  composer.json file)

```
"require-dev": {
     "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

**2** - Run *composer update* in main laravel root dir.

**3** - In your test classes use fully qualified names (namespace prefixed with )

```
<?php
class SomeTest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {
   public function createApplication()
   {
       $unitTesting = true;
       $testEnvironment = 'testing';
       return require __DIR__.'/../../../../bootstrap/start.php';
   }
   public function testSomething()
   {
       $this->assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

**4** - To run workbench package tests, go to package directory and run main phpunit

```
# in workbench/package/vendor dir run
../../../vendor/bin/phpunit
```

**5** - Output Green flag recognizing laravel app third party packages

```
marcanuy@bolso-server:~/public_html/pkgtesting/workbench/my/pack$ ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit --debug
PHPUnit 3.7.31 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/marcanuy/public_html/pkgtesting/workbench/my/pack/phpunit.xml


Starting test 'SomeTest::testSomething'.
.

Time: 64 ms, Memory: 6.25Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: Have you done this before? For me this doesn't change anything :-/ ( + it's a clean laravel install )

Comment: Yes, recently I have been struggling with similar issues trying to test a package without introducing new packages, I got it working fine here: https://github.com/marcanuy/popularity/blob/master/tests/StatsTest.php then I run my tests from package dir like ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit

Comment: It's strange because if I add the namespace like you have done in my test I receive the same error you are receiving, after removing it works fine, did you run dump-autoloads?

Comment: Yes, I did run `php artisan dump-autoload` from the root of my app. It did even mention that it considered my workbench. I'll have a look at your repository. Maybe that's gonna help. Anyways this won't work if I wan't to use travis-ci, right?

Comment: Not sure because I didn't use travis-ci with a Laravel package yet, but probably a custom script can be set up.

Comment: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Webseiten/acme/workbench/acme/foo/tests/TestCase.php

Above suggestion doesn't work since app can access workbench vendor, but workbench can't access app vendor (again same as what I reply above). So when you test from within a workbench, Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase it not available.

Comment: **As I replied above** it works, I've improved the answer showing it.